# How to redirect to another mvc view with model after axios post

Tags: c#, vue.js, asp.net-mvc-5, model, axios

I have a landing page with a textbox and a button search, I created a vue instance in order to manage the button and message state during searching.

When I click button and data are filled to the model I want to redirect to another view called "Detail" in order to show data

How can I solve this issue?

Below my tests

#### My script

```
new Vue({
    el: '#vm',
        data: {
            requestCode: '12345',
            isLoading: false,
            buttonText: 'Search',
            message: ''
        },
        methods: {
            onClick: function () {
                let model = this;
                model.buttonText = 'Please wait...';
                model.isLoading = true;
                model.message = '';

                axios({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: '/home/GetDataFromCode',
                    data: {
                        "requestCode": model.requestCode
                    }
                })
                .then(function (response) {
                    model.message = response.data.message;                          

                    if (response.data.success) {

                        // Here I have my model filled correctly
                        // How I can redirect to another view with model???
                        // My model is (response.data.customer)
                    }
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    model.message = error.message;
                });
                .finally(function () {
                    model.buttonText = 'Search';
                    model.isLoading = false;
                });
        }
    }
})
```

#### My cshtml page

```
<div id="vm">
    <div class="uk-margin-small">
        <div class="uk-inline uk-width-1-1 uk-text-center">                    
            <input type="text" v-model="requestCode" class="uk-input uk-text-center" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="uk-margin-bottom">
        <button id="btnSearch" v-on:click="onClick" type="button" class="uk-button uk-button-primary uk-width-1-1">
            <span>{{ buttonText }}</span>
            <div v-show="isLoading" uk-spinner="ratio: 0.5"></div>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="uk-margin-small">
        <div class="uk-inline uk-width-1-1 uk-text-center">
            <h5 style="height: 30px; text-transform: none">{{ message }}</h5>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### My controller

```
[HttpPost]
public dynamic GetDataFromCode(string requestCode)
{            
    Customer customer = new Customer()
    {
        RequestCode = requestCode,
        Name = "Harrison",
        Surname = "Ford"
    }

    return Json(new { success = true, customer = customer }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); 

}
```

Thanks in advance

R1g3L

Comment: If your view is in your server routes then a simple `window.location = '/your-route'` will do. If your view is another Vue component you might have to set up a Vue router and wrap your two views in that router component.

Comment: Hi Kevin, I tried but I have to pass whole model (response.data.customer) and with window.location isn't possible

Comment: `response.data.customer` returns json right? If it does then load that json data into the new view, is this view a Vue component?

Comment: Customer returns json and I have a simply view in mvc controller ```public ActionResult Detail(Customer customer)
        {
            return View(customer);
        }```

Comment: Create a new Vue component, and load that data into the vue component. You will need Vue router for this